# How can I edit Header tag in my Luma theme Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

In which file path `<header>` tag is available in Magento2? I need to customize the default `header` of the Magneto Luma theme.

Updated: I already checked header.phtml file but didn't find header tag.

Updated 1: I need to add below HTML inside the header.

i need to add inside the header tag..

```
<div class="headerTop">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="index.html">
                                <img src="img/logo.png">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="search_block">
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group search_box">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Search the store">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex userAction">
                            <ul class="topNav">
                                <li>
                                    Currency :
                                    <select class="select_currency">
                                        <option>INR</option>
                                    </select>
                                </li>
                                <li class="d-md-block d-none">                                  
                                    <select class="select_currency">
                                        <option>Select Language</option>
                                    </select>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=""><img src="img/paint_ic.png" alt=""></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=""><img src="img/user_ic.png" alt=""></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=""><img src="img/fav_ic.png" alt=""></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="cart.php"><img src="img/cart_ic.png" alt=""></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="navbar-dark d-flex justify-content-end d-lg-none">
                                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: ok, you want to edit header for luma theme right?

Comment: yes, I want to edit the header of luma. I have already overridden the luma theme.

Comment: so bro let me know what you want to add

Comment: because you can not directly find it.

Comment: updated my question, I will dynamic all things but where to add above HTML.

Comment: Yes, I will share you one answer but you need also some customize too.

Comment: have you checked it?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways but here I can share one simple way to override vendor.
1.please override vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
code here
replace below code

```
<container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-">




                <container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel header">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
                            <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to Content</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="Magento_Store::switch/languages.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\ViewModel\SwitcherUrlProvider</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation" name="top.links">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
            </container>
```

to

```
<container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-">

                <container name="test_block" label="Home DiscountBanner" as="test_block" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="test_block">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="home_discount_banner_template" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/test_block.phtml">
                </block>
                 </container>


                <container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel header">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
                            <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to Content</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="Magento_Store::switch/languages.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\ViewModel\SwitcherUrlProvider</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation" name="top.links">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
            </container>
```

2. please add one file in vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header/test_block.phtml

```
<div class="headerTop">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="index.html">
                                <img src="img/logo.png">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="search_block">
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group search_box">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Search the store">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex userAction">
                            <ul class="topNav">
                                <li>
                                    Currency :
                                    <select class="select_currency">
                                        <option>INR</option>
                                    </select>
                                </li>
                                <li class="d-md-block d-none">                                  
                                    <select class="select_currency">
                                        <option>Select Language</option>
                                    </select>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=""><img src="img/paint_ic.png" alt=""></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=""><img src="img/user_ic.png" alt=""></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=""><img src="img/fav_ic.png" alt=""></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="cart.php"><img src="img/cart_ic.png" alt=""></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="navbar-dark d-flex justify-content-end d-lg-none">
                                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and you will make the cache clear and check it.
this is for static you need to change hide some blocks ok.

Hope it works.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find header tag in vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\page_layout\1column.xml

```
<container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
```